# can we change the path of java installed folder?how?

Tags: java, hadoop, installation, installation-path

I am learning `Hadoop`.
On my windows system java is installed at `C:/Program files/Java` , but the problem is, I believe the white space in `program files`.

After setting all hadoop configuration files, When I run the command `namenode format` it give the following error.

```
$ bin/hadoop namenode -format bin/hadoop: line 350: C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

So is there any way by which i can change the java folder location to `C:/Java` from `C:/Program files/Java`

Thanks.

Comment: need add your java folder's path to Windows PATH

Comment: You can copy "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71" to "C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_71" directly and update your JAVA_HOME and PATH env variable according to the new path.

Comment: @Mahendra and update the registrey.

Comment: Per my understanding `Hadoop` will only look for `JAVA_HOME` env variable and `java` in PATH , not for any registry entry. So for Hadoop purpose registry updation can be ignored.

Comment: previously i was worried about that registry stuff thats why i posted this question. but now i did what Mr. Mahendra said,just copy pasted and updated the variables.thanks, and its working without any problem atleast my hadoop setup is working fine. i hope other software will not get affected.

Comment: for information, how do i update the registry @Peter Lawrey

Comment: You need to use regedit to find the entries with the old path and edit them. (Welcome to Windows ;)

Comment: welcome to windows world.. okay.. another topic for another time. thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy pasting the java folder to **C:/Java** from **C:/Program files/Java** and updating the environment variables with new path worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to move your java installation, you can try following possibilities:

1. set your java path within quotation
2. use the `~` operand -> your path is then `C:\Program~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_71`

Comment: copy pasted the java folder in desired manner and updated the env variable and it worked fine. and yes i'll see if using '~' will work or not. thanks